# Split list of student according to their mark - haskell

Tags: list, haskell, custom-data-type

There is a list of students where

```
data Student = Student {
   name :: String,
   mark :: Mark
} deriving Show

data Mark = F|E|D|C|B|A deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

I need to split it like that `[(mark,[students with this mark])]`

I made something like this:

```
splitToGroups :: [Student] -> [(Mark, [String])]    
splitToGroups [] = []
splitToGroups students = foldr funct [] students where
    funct student [] = [(mark student,[name student])]
    funct student ((x,xs):xss) | mark student == x = ((x,(name student):xs):xss)
                               | otherwise = (mark student,[name student]):(x,xs):xss
```

but it works incorectly. Maybe someone knows how it could be done..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't manually recurse if you can use standard tools. You can do this with sorting and grouping, but IMO preferrable is to use the types to express that you're building an *associative* result, i.e. a map from marks to students.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

splitToGroups :: [Student] -> Map.Map Mark [String]
splitToGroups students = Map.fromListWith (<>)
     [ (sMark, [sName])
     | Student sName sMark <- students ]
```

(If you want a list in the end, just use `Map.toList`.)

Comment: can you please explain to me or direct me to where I could find out how it works?

Comment: Reading [the documentation to `Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html) would probably get you some way.

Answer (score 1):

If you view Student as a tupple, your function has this type: `splitToGroups :: [(Mark,String)] -> [(Mark, [String])]`.
So you need a function with type: `[(a,b)] -> [(a,[b])]`.

Using Hoogle: [search results](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5B%28a%2Cb%29%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%28a%2C%5Bb%5D%29%5D&scope=set%3Astackage)

I get the following functions:

`groupSort :: Ord k => [(k, v)] -> [(k, [v])]`

`collectSndByFst :: Ord a => [(a, b)] -> [(a, [b])]`

They should solve your problem, remember to import the modules listed in the link to make them work. You should make a funtion that maps from `Student -> (Mark, String)` first.